# Can you get heatmap density to be determined by the figure of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, leaflet, folium

I am making a heatmap where I want the density to be determined by the value of a cell in a Pandas data frame, instead of the heatmap being determined by the amount of data points in certain areas.

```
HeatMap(data=df[["latitude", "longitude", "price_total"]].groupby(
        ["latitude", "longitude"]
    ).sum().reset_index().values.tolist(),
    radius=8,
    max_zoom=13).add_to(base_map)
```

How can I alter the code to make the heatmap density be determined by column `df["price_total"]`?

Answer (score 0):

What data is your heat map expecting? Without knowing that or what your data looks like, I can only guess. If you want a sum of prices in your matrix, you can form it like this:

```
Heatmap(pd.crosstab(index = df['latitude'], columns = df['longitude'], 
        values = df['price_total'], aggfunc = 'sum').fillna(0))
```

Comment: My data frame looks like this: df["borough", "longitude", "latitude", "price_total"], and I want the heatmap to display density based on the value of "price_total". Maybe a heatmap isn't the way to go? Could I use folium.Circle() and base the radius on my df["price_total"] instead?